# How to receive from a queue and publish it into a topic?

Tags: java, session, jms, message-queue

I am trying to receive a message from a queue and publish it into a topic. I have a QueueSession instance but it cannot be used to create a topic. If I understand correctly, QueueSession is only used for receiving messages from a queue and sending messages to another queue. How can I mix it up - receiving from a queue and publishing it into a topic in a single session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about all of the domain-specific classes and use the unified domain available in JMS 1.1.  Substitute the classes as follows:

- QueueConnectionFactory --> ConnectionFactory
- QueueSession --> Session
- Queue --> Destination

Once you switch to the unified domain, the application does not need to know whether a destination is a queue or a topic.  For example, if your app has two managed objects `myInputDest` and `myOuputDest` you can assign either of these to a queue or a topic in your managed object definitions (sometimes referred to as the .bindings file) in any combination.  You can read from the queue and write to a topic, read from a topic and write to a queue, go queue-to-queue or topic-to-topic and all of this is resolved at run time and can change between program invocations just by changing the managed objects.

There is some sample code that demonstrates this in the IdeveloperWorks article *[Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0610_woolf/0610_woolf.html)*

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a [TopicSession](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TopicSession.html) and [TopicPublisher](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TopicPublisher.html) for the destination topic, but do this outside of your queue message handler--for example at the same time you create the QueueSession and subscribe to queue. In the queue message handler, you will then call `publish(message)` on the TopicPublisher instance.

Comment: so you're saying i maintain two sessions (TopicSession and QueueSession) in parallel?

Comment: Yes. A QueueSession for receiving messages on the queue, and a TopicSession for publishing the message again on the topic